# Change Span to Input and update my database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm currently using this snippet code i grabbed from some stackoverflow post,

It converts a span element to input so i can edit and goes back to span after

how can i make it so that when the input converts back to span it updates its value on a mysql database?

```js
/**
  We're defining the event on the `body` element, 
  because we know the `body` is not going away.
  Second argument makes sure the callback only fires when 
  the `click` event happens only on elements marked as `data-editable`
*/
$('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function() {

  var $el = $(this);

  var $input = $('<input/>').val($el.text());
  $el.replaceWith($input);

  var save = function() {
    var $p = $('<span data-editable />').text($input.val());
    $input.replaceWith($p);
  };

  /**
    We're defining the callback with `one`, because we know that
    the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
    any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
    Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
    will be applied again.
  */
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on <span data-editable> EDIT</span>
```

Comment: You need an ajax post call to write to the db

Comment: It is unclear what part of this is causing you problems. And if your answer is "all of it", then your question is too broad.  You will need an ajax request, PHP code to handle the request and make a connection to your DB, and an SQL query to insert or update the value in the DB.

Comment: the span to input and back to span is working on my code, i just don't know how i can pass the data stored on the input to the php that will update my mysql database

Answer (score -1):

You should handle it inside the `save` function

```js
/**
  We're defining the event on the `body` element, 
  because we know the `body` is not going away.
  Second argument makes sure the callback only fires when 
  the `click` event happens only on elements marked as `data-editable`
*/
$('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function() {

  var $el = $(this);

  var $input = $('<input/>').val($el.text());
  $el.replaceWith($input);

  var save = function() {
    var $p = $('<span data-editable />').text($input.val());
    $input.replaceWith($p);
    // AJAX call to your backend to save $input.val()
  };

  /**
    We're defining the callback with `one`, because we know that
    the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
    any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
    Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
    will be applied again.
  */
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on <span data-editable> EDIT</span>
```